# Visual Studio 2015 SQL Server Project. Manage linked server having references to multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, linked-server

I have created a SQL server project in Visual Studio 2015. We have a linked server which is referring to multiple databases. I am unable to find a way to manage this linked server and its references to multiple databases. I am unable to build the solution due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate type of object on SSDT for linked servers as references. Instead, you should add database reference(s) for your remote database(s) specifying their location as "Different database, different server". [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2014/10/15/correctly-handling-linked-server-objects-in-ssdt/) this process is described in more detail.

You should be able to use the same SQLCMD variable as a server name for all your remote databases, though I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: We are using 5 databases of linked server. So here do we need to add 5 different projects for each database.

Comment: @DeveloperRego, exactly. And it their objects reference each other, you probably will have to resolve this dependency graph, as well. However, it's nearly not as frightening as it sounds if you will move all your database development into SSDT, because normally this needs to be done only once (in a while, maybe).

Comment: Hey @RogerWolf, I got your point, In my SQL Server Management Studio I can see the references to linked server are underlined in red but executed successfully. Can it be the reason for error #71561 in SQL Server db project in visual studio. If yes then please suggest any way to resolve it in visual studio.

Comment: @PankajKumar, it depends on how you reference them in code. Here you can find some solutions - https://stackoverflow.com/q/12161392/3925232

Comment: Thank you @RogerWolf for the inputs. Will try these solutions once get beck from Christmas vacation and keep you posted if more inputs needed for this concept. Wishing you Merry Christmas in advance.